# cublassgemm for row-major matrix

Tags: cuda, cublas

I really tried to implement a function in C to multiply to row-major matrix in cublas. I don't know where I mistaking.
In the function below A, B and C are pointers to an row matrix correctly
allocated.
I'd like to keep the option of translate a matrix before perform the product.
The function below is not working.

```
void matrixMul(cublasHandle_t handle,float *A,float *B,float *C, int m,int n,int k,int transA,int transB){

    cublasStatus_t stat ; // CUBLAS functions status
    float alfa = 1;
    float beta = 0;

    int
    ma = transA ? n:m,
    na = transA ? m:n,


    nb = transB ? k:n,
    mb = transB ? n:k;


    if(na!=mb){
        puts("Something wrong");
    }

    //(mb,nb)(ma,na) = (mb,na)
    stat= cublasSgemm_v2(handle, (cublasOperation_t) transB, (cublasOperation_t)transA,
                nb,ma,mb,&alfa,
                B,k,
                A,n,&beta,
                C,m);

    switch (stat) {
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS:
            puts("Sucess");
            break;
        default:
            printf(">>>>ERRO  %d<<<<\n",stat);
            break;
    }

}
```

The entire source code

```
// Utilities and system includes
#include <assert.h>
#include <helper_string.h>  // helper for shared functions common to CUDA Samples

// CUDA runtime
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>

// CUDA and CUBLAS functions
#include <helper_functions.h>

void getFromDevice(float *h_A,float *d_A,int size){
    //printf("Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device\n");
    cudaError_t err  = cudaMemcpy(h_A, d_A, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector A from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}
//A = (m,n)
//B = (n,k)
//C = (m,k)
void matrixMul(cublasHandle_t handle,float *A,float *B,float *C, int m,int n,int k,int transA,int transB){

    cublasStatus_t stat ; // CUBLAS functions status
    float alfa = 1;
    float beta = 0;

    int
    ma = transA ? n:m,
    na = transA ? m:n,


    nb = transB ? k:n,
    mb = transB ? n:k;


    if(na!=mb){
        puts("Something wrong");
    }

    //(mb,nb)(ma,na) = (mb,na)
    stat= cublasSgemm_v2(handle, (cublasOperation_t) transB, (cublasOperation_t)transA,
                nb,ma,mb,&alfa,
                B,k,
                A,n,&beta,
                C,m);

    switch (stat) {
        case CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS:
            puts("Sucess");
            break;
        default:
            printf(">>>>ERRO  %d<<<<\n",stat);
            break;
    }

}


float *mallocfDevice(int size){
    float *d_C = NULL;
    cudaError_t err  = cudaMalloc((void **)&d_C, size * sizeof(float));

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate device vector C (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }else{
        size_t freeM,  total;
        cudaMemGetInfo  (   &freeM, &total);
        printf("MEM:%.3f\n",freeM,total,100 - ((double)freeM/total)*100 );
    }
    return d_C;
}



void printHostMatrix(int nl, int nc, float *h_s){
    for(int j = 0; j < nl ; j++) {
        for(int i = 0; i < (nc) ; i++){
            int idx = j*nc + i;
            printf("%.2f ", h_s[idx]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

}


void printfDeviceMatrix(float *d_s,int m, int p){
    float *h_s =(float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*m*p);
    getFromDevice(h_s,d_s,sizeof(float)*m*p);
    printHostMatrix(m,p,h_s);
    free(h_s);
}


void sendTofDevice(float *h_A,float *d_A,int size){
    //printf("Copy input data from the host memory to the CUDA device\n");
    cudaError_t err  = cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, size*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vector A from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}


int main(int argc,char **argv){

    int ma = 2,
        na = 3,
        mb = 3,
        nb = 2;

    float A[] = { 1,2,3,
                 4,5,6};
    float B[] = {7, 8,
                9,10,
                11,12};

    float *C = new float[ma*nb];



    float *d_a = mallocfDevice(ma*mb),
          *d_b = mallocfDevice(mb*nb),
          *d_c = mallocfDevice(ma*nb);

    sendTofDevice(A,d_a,ma*na);
    sendTofDevice(B,d_b,mb*nb);

    cublasHandle_t handle ; // CUBLAS context
    cublasCreate (&handle );

    puts("A");
    printfDeviceMatrix(d_a,ma,na);
    puts("B");
    printfDeviceMatrix(d_b,mb,nb);

    matrixMul(handle,  d_a,d_b,d_c,
                       ma,na,nb,0,0);

    puts("AB=C");
    printfDeviceMatrix(d_c,ma,nb);


}
```

Comment: Could you describe your problem in a bit more detail? "Not working" isn't very helpful, I'm afraid

Comment: I solved the problem. I didn't understand how to use the cublasgemm for row-major major matrix. I'll check the answer.

Comment: Could you please add a short answer explaining how you solved the problem? (answering your own questions is perfectly OK on [SO]) It will leave something behind for the next person who might find this via google

Comment: The answer of OrenNishry clarify me about dimensions of matrix. As I have to assume that the matrix is transposed their dimensions must be transposed as well during the gemm call.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

CUBLAS assumes that the matrix in the device is stored in column major:

"
where α and β are scalars, and A , B and C are matrices stored in column-major format with dimensions op ( A ) m × k , op ( B ) k × n and C m × n , respectively. Also, for matrix A

Read more at: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#ixzz3mSDJTWrM "

That means the matrix needs to be treated as differently on the device than on the host.

Comment: The CUBLAS APIs (like any BLAS), support operating on matrices stored in transposed order (ie. row major order), and the OP is trying to use this to perform a dot product.

Comment: It's possible to use matrices that are stored in row-major order with cublas,  and "the matrix needs to be treated as differently on the device than on the host" is nonsense.